# TCP WCF Service isn't executing Application_Start

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-7

**Problem:**
The Application_Start event is not being triggered in my WCF Service which contains a TCP endpoint.

**Background:**
I'm hitting trying to hit the service from a console app.  If the service is not yet started, the call will fail because Application_Start never fires.  However, if I explicitly start the service (hit the hosting web app from a browser) then and then call the service from the console app it works fine.

**Question:**
What gives?  If the only thing being hosted in the service application is a tcp endpoint does Appliction_Start of the HttpApplication never get triggered?  It makes sense to a certain degree as it is essentially being treated as a non-http application via WAS.  However, it doesn't make sense because it is being hosted in IIS.

Comment: You seem to have it back to front, application_start event fires as a result of the application starting not the other way round. Are you basically saying  that its doesn't spin up a worker process if you hit the endpoint from a console app but it does if you hit it with a browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Application_Start` will never be hit in a WAS hosted WCF service. This event is ASP.NET specific (no IIS specific), so unless you are hosting your WCF service in ASP.NET it won't be hit: and you are not as it is hosted by WAS.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I'm just gonna have to create a ServiceHostFactory and do my initialization there.